# System.in.read(); comparing

Tags: java

In my class we are starting to learn java, we were tasked to explain why this code:

```
import java.io.IOEXception;

 class Inputif {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

         char ch, ch2;

         System.out.print("Hit a key and press Enter: ");

         ch = (char) System.in.read();

         System.out.println("Hit a second key and press Enter: ");

         ch2 = (char) System.in.read();

         if (ch == ch2) System.out.println("Same"); else System.out.println("different"); 
   }
}
```

outputs this: 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkw7n.png)

in this screenshot i just started the program and typed "a" and then hit enter.

When I run the program it asks me to enter the first char, then it should ask me to enter the second one, but it skips that and prints out the "different" end. I don't know why.

The code should compare the two chars that the user inputs and if they are the same it should print "Same" else it should say "different".

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: The second key *is* Enter, or a newline.

Comment: A new line, enter should just confirm the selection.

Comment: They're the same thing.

Comment: I am a bit confused. After i enter the first char and confirm it with enter, it should ask me to do that for the second char again, but it skips that. Why?

Comment: your second character is the new line. when you press enter, you are actually creating a new line. If you print out your second character, you will see in the console that it actually is a new line.

Comment: Not to be too blunt, but are you asking us to explain the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes to your program to  give you some insigth into what is happening:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

    char ch, ch2;

    System.out.print("Hit a key and press Enter: ");

    ch = (char) System.in.read();

    System.out.println("Hit a second key and press Enter: ");

    ch2 = (char) System.in.read();
    int x1=ch;
    int x2 = ch2;
    System.out.println("x1="+x1+" | x2="+x2);
    if (ch == ch2) System.out.println("Same"); else System.out.println("different");
}
```

Run the above program two times :
 - type "a" and hit enter.
 - hit enter twice

Explication :
System.in is an instance Of InputStream and the read  method  of an InputStream https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html that "Reads the next byte of data from the input stream".
The problem is that when you re hitting enter you are adding an extra byte to the input stream and ALWAYS ch2 will store it.
 *Note : x1, x2 will display the ASCII codes of the chars you  hit.

Answer (score 1):

In these situations you may want to use a Scanner:

```
class Inputif {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

        char ch, ch2;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Hit a key and press Enter: ");

        ch = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Hit a second key and press Enter: ");

        ch2 = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        if (ch == ch2)
            System.out.println("Same");
        else
            System.out.println("different");
    }
}
```

It's just an example. Your problem is the newline, so maybe Scanner can help you here.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about scanners and asked my teacher why we don't use that instead, but he said that he wants an explanation, why this code doesn't work. I guess i should have had said that, but thanks anyways! Anything is helpful.

Comment: Yes. Use a scanner when you are reading text as text. With `(char)System.in.read()`, you are reading text as bytes with the terminal's character encoding (whatever it is) and then casting them as if the character encoding was ISO-8859-1 (due to a characteristic of UTF-16, which is the encoding of `char`). Try typing (or pasting) ŝ. You'll get "garbage" due to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as already said your second read from Scanner reads the something after your first char, and that something is new line (or Enter as you think). You're not convinced so, execution of this code:

```
public class Helper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        char ch, ch2;

        System.out.print("Hit a key and press Enter: ");
        ch = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println("your first read contains " + ch);

        System.out.println("Hit a second key and press Enter: ");
        ch2 = (char) System.in.read();
        System.out.println("your second read contains " + ch2);


        if (ch == ch2) System.out.println("Same");
        else System.out.println("different");

    }
}
```

outputs:

1. Hit a key and press Enter: a
2. your first read contains a
3. Hit a second key and press Enter:
4. your second read contains
5. 
6. different

See, in line 5. is printed new line...

Now, if you hit Enter twice (for the first and the second char) the result **will be** *Same*!

P.S.
You can use the debugger instead of printing to the console, *and* it would be the preferred way!